# Arrange List<> in ascending order

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list whose type is string which i want to arrange in ascending order

```
listCustomFields = new List<String>() { "FirstName", "MiddleName", "Class" };
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this

```
listCustomFields.sort();
```

Comment: Hey @MurtazaMunshi I don't understand why you select this answer. Marcin's answer is faster and better written. If there are more than one answer they looks like the same, choose fastest and best quality one.

Comment: Sorry I am new to stack overflow i donno the rules here. I will keep your words in mind. Thanx for guiding me.

Answer (score 30):

You can use LINQ [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) method (it will generate new `List<string>` with items sorted):

```
var ordered = listCustomField.OrderBy(x => x).ToList();
```

or [`List<T>.Sort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/w56d4y5z.aspx) method (it will sort the list in place):

```
listCustomField.Sort();
```

Comment: i think this is the better answer because i needed to do it in descending order, and linq supports this

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`OrderBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.orderby.aspx) like;

> Sorts the elements of a sequence in **ascending order.**

```
listCustomFields = listCustomFields.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();
```

As an alternative, you can use [`List<T>.Sort` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) also.

```
List<String> listCustomFields = new List<String>() { "FirstName", "MiddleName", "Class" };
listCustomFields = listCustomFields.OrderBy(n => n).ToList();

foreach (var item in listCustomFields)
{
   Console.WriteLine(item);
}
```

Output will be;

```
Class
FirstName
MiddleName
```

Here a [**DEMO**](http://ideone.com/gZcI8e).

Answer (score 1):

You do not need LINQ for that: rather than creating a sorted copy, you can sort your list in place by calling [`Sort()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b0zbh7b6.aspx) method on it:

```
listCustomFields.Sort();
```

The order is implicitly ascending. If you need to change that, supply a custom comparer.