# How to use OrderBy to sort a custom object ascending by Date

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a collection of a custom object as follows:

```
public struct Record {
    public string Caller { get; set; }
    public DateTime Started { get; set; }
    public string Dialed { get; set; }
    public decimal Duration { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public Switch Switch { get; set; }
}

public static List<Record> Records { get; set; }
```

Using LINQ, how can I sort `Records` in ascending order using the value stored in `Record.Started` ?

Comment: `var sortedRecords = Records.OrderBy(r => r.Started)`

Comment: I'm just wondering how a simple search for "LINQ ascending order" didn't show you many answers. I just searched for that and the first result was on Stackoverflow and answered this question.

Comment: That is half the questions on SO @Jashaszun

Comment: The confusion is all the information I could find show it returns a list of strings, not objects -- so I am under the impression that `r => r.Started` would only return a list of `Started` not of `Record` --- for example this >> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18545988/arrange-list-in-ascending-order

Comment: @austinwernli And that is a sad state of affairs...

Comment: `r => r.Started` is just the criteria; its not going to split up your object (need more code for that)

Comment: @austinwernli Excuse me for wanting to ensure that the 'assumption' was valid or not before 'testing' on 200,000,000 records thanks.

Comment: As @austinwernli implies, it is true that with a simple google search for a tutorial of any sort on LINQ you would have found your answer, and much more. I'm surprised, Sanuel Jackson, that with your 1.4k rep you're not better at using SO as you should.

Comment: @Plutonix - thank you for clarifying, and treating this question with a mature perspective.

Comment: @Jashaszun - I did a google search and sorry, but found no examples on object sorting -- only simple 1-dimensional arrays like string or int.  If I had found something I wouldn't have taken the time to post this question. Further, as you know, Google is becoming a real cesspool for broken/wrong/dated information, and only limits viewing to the first 100 results of any search.

Comment: Sure would have been nice for  >>  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3007470/custom-sort-logic-in-orderby-using-linq?rq=1    to have come up in results before posting the question.  Nice how it didn't show in any search request, or while writing the article.  Sometimes the latent 'Related' shows more accurate results than the same engine while typing or searching. -- added it for close vote.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `OrderBy` method:

```
Records.OrderBy(record => record.Started)
```

or:

```
from r in Records
order by r.Started
select r
```

Answer (score 1):

Could it be this easy?

```
records.OrderBy(r=>r.Started)
```

Comment: wouldn't that just return a list of the dates, and not the `Record` object ?

Comment: Nope, that would happen if you use Select().

Comment: Makes more sense now.  The other articles on here (possibly my misunderstanding or really not clarified) are of a more simple nature sorting <string> or whatever and thus returning an array of that type. I didn't know it always returns whatever custom type is passed.

Comment: It actually returns an `IOrderedEnumerable<Record>` and the sort is only performed when the sequence is materialised https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx see remarks